# Converting string to int in linq to entities

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

i want to convert following sql query in linq .This query give me proper output but in linq i used conversion function it gives me an error.

```
SELECT min(cast(cliAckNo as INT))-1 FROM dbo.Cli_ClientInfoMaster  WHERE cast(cliAckNo as int )>5001 and cast(cliAckNo as int)<100001
```

Comment: in my db i saved **cliAckNo** as varchar now i want to convert it to int .i try all method but not luck.i am using linq to entities.

Comment: You can use int.Parse() to convert a string to an int.

Comment: Please post your linq statement